# Not compile library file of Svg image Loader

Tags: android, svg, android-gradle-plugin

I  compile this dependancy in my project:

```
compile 'com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.1'
```

Is not sync properly and give the follownig errors:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.1.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.1.      Unable to resolve
>   dependency for app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not
>   resolve com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.1.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#3 Could not resolve
>   com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.1

I also write dependency

```
    allprojects {
          repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()
           maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'; }
  // but still not working....
    }
    }
```

Gradle Files:

project file

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
 }

 allprojects {
   repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
 }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

App Gradle File

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edru.techxpose.co.recycleviewdemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


implementation 'com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
 core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'

implementation files('libs/svg-android-2.0.5.jar')
  }
```

Comment: please format your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

project file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App Gradle File

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edru.techxpose.co.recycleviewdemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


implementation 'com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'
implementation files('libs/svg-android-2.0.5.jar')
  }
```

Comment: Not Working .still facing same issue

Comment: @HarwinderSingh please copy paste you 2 grandle files so we can help you.

Comment: @HarwinderSingh try this code and sync project again, if you see same error try to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart. tell me if it is work

Comment: @HarwinderSingh upvote if its possible, thank you a lot have a nice day coding

Comment: i am getting one more problem. plz fix it

Comment: @HarwinderSingh sure tell me or post a question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702974/svgloader-not-working-without-reffernce-of-current-class

Comment: open this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702974/svgloader-not-working-without-reffernce-of-current-class

Comment: i take a look and i answer as soon as possible

Comment: buddy plz give me solution